# Using R to Convert VCI JSON.GZ file to CSV

Tags: r, data-conversion, gzip, jsonlite

I have a file that ends with ".vci_json.gz". My goal is to read the contents of this file using R and write contents in a structured table in CSV format.

I have attempted using the `jsonlite` package for R like...

```
dataset1 <- suppressWarnings(stream_in(gzfile("data.vci_json")))
```

... but I get the following error message "opening gzfile input connection.

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection".
```

Any thoughts how I can get this data in a CSV format?

Comment: Is there a reason you left off the ".gz" part in the file name when calling `gzfile()`?

Comment: @MrFlick, when I download the file that's how it appears on my desktop--without '.gz' even though the full extension is ".vci_json.gz" before downloading the file.

Comment: Is your operating system hiding the file extension from you? What does `list.files()` show?

Comment: I used "list.files()" and yes, it appears to be hiding the file extension. It's showing "Custom Office Templates" for this file and showing the extension as ".vci_json.gz".

Comment: @MrFlick When I add the '.gz' extension to gzfile I get the following error message. `opening gzfile input connection.
Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       {
                     (right here) ------^
closing gzfile input connection.`

Comment: What exactly is in this file? File extensions can lie.